# How to apply filter in DevExpress Scheduler

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a scheduler in my WPF project and I want to filter my appointments but I could not find out how to raise the `SchedulerStorage.FilterAppointment` event when I e.g. press a button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SchedulerStorage.FilterAppointment](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfSchedulerSchedulerStorage_FilterAppointmenttopic) event fires each time the layout of the Scheduler Control is modified (when the control is resized, when new appointments are added, or existing ones are modified, etc.).
You can force the layout to be updated by calling the Scheduler View's [LayoutChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfSchedulerSchedulerViewBase_LayoutChangedtopic) method.